# How can I delete all words above a certain character length (in text from an input box)?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, character, words

If I input text into VB.Net 2010 (VB 10.0) (maybe via an input box?), would it be possible to create a program to delete all words with more than (for example) 4 characters in them, leaving me with only one, two or three letter words?

If so, how could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as I know, all the forms of input you're typically going to deal with are going to be readable in code as strings.

So figure out how to grab that string and then figure out how to 'parse' each word.  As you're parsing, you'll want to then choose whether to keep it or throw it away.  You'll also want to store your answer somewhere as you're going along.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use VB.Net, but in C#, which is .net, I would just "split" the text on delimiters, then roll through the array of words, keeping only the small ones.

Like so:

```
string text = "this is my test text with some reallllllllly long words";


List<string> outputList = new List<string>();

// and maybe some punctuation chars as well here...
string[] words = text.Split(new char[]{' ','\n','\r','\t'});
foreach (string word in words)
{
    if (word.Length < 4)
        outputList.Add(word);
}

// now outputList == list of small words!
```

I believe Split() has a parameter that tells it to ignore empty strings - you'll probably want that too.

Comment: `SplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` is what you're looking for.  I.e., `string[] words = text.Split(new char[] {' ', '\n', '\r', '\t'}, SplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` would ignore any empty strings from the split.